# How to get single quotes instead of double in xslt

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Please help me how to get single quotes instead of double in xslt
http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEvL

expected output:

> aav'c'dd

```
<xsl:variable
name="name"
select="'aav&quot;c&quot;dd'"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way...

```
<xsl:variable name='name' select='"aav&apos;c&apos;dd"'/>
```